# This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after moving forward is not supported - Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In Zend app, I use `Zend\Db\TableGateway` and `Zend\Db\Sql` to retrieve data  data from MySQL database as below.

Model -

```
public function getCandidateEduQualifications($id)
{
    $id  = (int) $id;

    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Sql\Select $select) use ($id)
    {
        $select->where
            ->AND->NEST->equalTo('candidate_id', $id)
            ->AND->equalTo('qualification_category', 'Educational');
    });

    return $rowset;
}
```

View -

I just iterate $rowset and echo in view. But it gives error when try to echo two or more times. Single iteration works.

> This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after
>   moving forward is not supported

I can solve it by loading it to another array in view. But is it the best way ? Is there any other way to handle this ?

```
$records = array();
foreach ($edu_qualifications as $result) {
    $records[] = $result;
}
```

EDIT -

`$resultSet->buffer();` solved the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You receive this `Exception` because this is expected behavior. Zend uses [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to obtain its `Zend\Db\ResultSet\Resultset` which is returned by `Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway`. PDO result sets use a forward-only cursor by default, meaning you can only loop through the set once.

For more information about cursors check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/05/13/understanding-cursor-options-in-the-sql-server-driver-for-php.aspx) article.

As the `Zend\Db\ResultSet\Resultset` implements the PHP [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) you can extract an array of the set using the `Zend\Db\ResultSet\Resultset:toArray()` method or using the `iterator_to_array()` function.  Do be careful though about using this function on potentially large datasets! One of the best things about cursors is precisely that they avoid bringing in everything in one go, in case the data set is too large, so there are times when you won't want to put it all into an array at once.

Comment: What about buffer() ?

Comment: With `Zend\Db\ResultSet\Resultset::buffer()` each time `Zend\Db\ResultSet\Resultset::current()` is invoked the current row will be kept in `Zend\Db\ResultSet\Resultset::$buffer` as you loop through the set. This loop could be a `foreach()`. So basicly on the first `foreach()` the data will come from your database and on the second loop it will come from `Zend\Db\ResultSet\Resultset::$buffer`. If you are going to use `Zend\Db\ResultSet\Resultset::buffer()` you have to invoke it before you loop through the set because the set has to know it needs to buffer.

Comment: You can loop over the same result twice but you have to explicitly tell the `Zend\Db\ResultSet\Resultset` to buffer the data. My guess is that its not enabled by default because with large data you'll be consuming lots of memory.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, It looks like when we use Mysql and want to iterate $resultSet, this error will happen, b/c Mysqli only does 
forward-moving result sets (Refer to this post: [ZF2 DB Result position forwarded?](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ZF2-DB-Result-position-forwarded-td4655406.html))

I came across this problem too. But when add following line, it solved:

```
$resultSet->buffer();
```

but in this mentioned post, it suggest use following line. I just wonder why, and what's difference of them:

```
$resultSet->getDataSource()->buffer();
```

Comment: Although the technical explanation on the accepted solution is important, this should be the accepted solution as it is the easier approach to solve the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
public function fetchAll()
    {

        $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select(); 
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        $resultSet->buffer();
        $resultSet->next();

        return $resultSet;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = new Zend\Db\Sql($your_adapter);

$select = $sql->select('your_table_name'); 

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);

$results = $statement->execute();

$resultSet = new ResultSet();

$resultSet->initialize($results);

$result = $resultSet->toArray();
```