# Need dynamic column information from Zend Paginator Object

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db-select, zend-paginator

I am building a plugin for grid listing ( for my personal use of course ). Now I integrated ZF2 Paginator as in link http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/tutorial.pagination.html . I am using DB Select for Paginator (Not Array). I need fields name as dynamic one, So i can iterate them, Something like that

```
<?php $headers = $this->paginator->getFirstRow()->getColumns(); ?>
<tr>
<?php foreach ($headers as $col) : ?>
    <th><?php echo $col; ?></th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($this->paginator as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($row->getColumns() as $col) : ?>
        <td><?php echo $row->{$col}; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As this is practice project, I really no need to integrate some already existed 3rd party grid solutions. I just want to know if something similar like above is possible using Zend Paginator API ?

**UPDATE : Problem finally fixed. Solution is very much match to @netiul's solution with some modifications .**

In Plugin Helper :

```
$resultSet = $paginator->getIterator(); 

$columnNames = array_keys(get_object_vars($resultSet->getArrayObjectPrototype()));

$grid .= '<thead><tr>';
foreach($columnNames as $header)
{
    $grid .= '<th>'.$header.'</th>';
}
$grid .= '</tr></thead>';

$grid .= '<tbody>';
foreach($resultSet as $row)
{
    $grid .= '<tr>';
    foreach($columnNames as $col)
    {
        $grid .= '<td>'.$row->$col.'</td>';
    }
}
$grid .= '</tbody>';
```

Also one change needed in Model (Alas I need to make this change outside plugin, don't now how to fix except a Model parent class which override by all project models  ).

I need to add resultset buffer to fix forward cursor error like [This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after moving forward is not supported - Zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567219/this-result-is-a-forward-only-result-set-calling-rewind-after-moving-forward) )

In Model :

```
public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
{
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
    $this->resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $this->resultSetPrototype->buffer();  // New Line added for buffer
    $this->resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Leads());
    $this->initialize();
}
```

Comment: Quite interesting question!

Comment: When `echo '<pre>'; print_r($paginator); exit();` is executed, it does show `[columns:protected] => Array ( [0] => * )` array if all the columns are selected or `[1] => id [2] => name [....]` if specific columns are selected. But not being able to fetch that array. Please do let us know if you find the solution. Will really appreciate.

Comment: Obviously Paginator object will have some of information, But accessing it as required is a question ? Again `*` is not a solution As Solution required resultset not query object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to recap your question: you want to output the contents of a paginator of which you don't know the columnnames, since they may be dynamic?

Let's assume we've a valid Paginator with results and unknown column names. These are the steps to correctly output them:

1. Fetch the column names of the first row and put them in an array.
2. Generate the header of the table/grid.
3. Use the array to walk over the rows to match the table header sequence.

That could look like as following.

```
$firstItem = reset($paginator->getIterator());
$columnNames = array_keys(get_object_vars($firstItem));

// optional do some sorting here like `sort($columNames)`

echo '<thead><tr>';
foreach ($columnNames as $columnName) {
    echo '<th>' . $columnName . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr></thead>';

echo '<tbody>';
foreach ($paginator as $item) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($columnNames as $columnName) {
        echo '<td>' . $item->$columnName . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
```

Comment: Its look promising, I am definitely checking it .

Comment: Problem fixed with some required modifications (in my question updates). Accepting your answer.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.