# ZF2 - Iterating over a HydratingResultSet

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm using TableGateway's selectWith function to return a HydratingResultSet of entities. I need to iterate through each of the entities of the result set - not sure how I'm to do it, but using a foreach gives the error "This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after moving forward is not supported".

What I was trying to do is basically:

```
$res = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($query);
foreach($res as $r) {...}
```

What am I doing wrong? We're using Zend Framework 2.3. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might this be a solution to your problem? Check the edit.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567219/this-result-is-a-forward-only-result-set-calling-rewind-after-moving-forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to buffer() result before itarate or get an array - toArray()

```
$res = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($query);

$res->buffer(); // you need to buffer result first
//$res = $res->toArray(); // or transform resultset to array but I prefere more to buffer

foreach($res as $r) {...} // first iterate 
foreach($res as $r) {...} // second iterate
```

but be careful this isn't advisable on the large results.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$res` before reaching the `foreach` loop...

`HydratingResultSet` is forward only result set(data has not been loaded from the database) and once you iterate throw it , you can't do it again.

to use the Resultset multiple times, you need to load all the data at once.
`$res->buffer()` or `$res = $res->toArray()`

what code do you have between `$res` and `foreach` ???

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's the weird thing though. I have absolutely nothing between the selectWith and the foreach! It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @riyunoa are u 100% sure that `$res` has never been used before reaching `foreach` ? can you post the full code from starting of `select`?